# react-router-redux 5: Maintaining store state history across navigation

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-redux, react-router-dom

I'm currently developing a react redux application. When i navigate with previous and next buttons in the browser the url is changing and routes gets correctly rendered. However, the redux store keeps the latest state and doesn't time travel across navigation, the only state that gets changed is the router location state.

Here is my redux store:

```
import {applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore} from "redux";
import reducers from "../reducers";
import history from '../history'
import {routerMiddleware, routerReducer} from "react-router-redux";

const middleware = routerMiddleware(history)

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    router: routerReducer
  }),
  applyMiddleware(middleware)
)

export default store
```

The index file of the application is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
import {registerObserver} from "react-perf-devtool";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";
import {ConnectedRouter} from "react-router-redux";
import history from './history'

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept()
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
registerObserver();
registerServiceWorker()
```

The history is as follows:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

const history = createHistory()

export default history
```

Finally, here are the reducers:

```
import {SET_USER_LOCATION, SET_NEARBY_SHOPS} from "../constants/action-types";

const initialState = {
  userLocation: {
    latitude: 0.,
    longitude: 0.
  },
  nearbyShops: {
    shops: [],
    radiusOfSearch: 0.
  }
}

const userLocation = (state = initialState.userLocation, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_USER_LOCATION:
      return { latitude: action.payload.latitude, longitude: action.payload.longitude }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const nearbyShops = (state = initialState.nearbyShops, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_NEARBY_SHOPS:
      return { shops: [...action.payload.shops], radiusOfSearch: action.payload.radiusOfSearch }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const reducers = { userLocation, nearbyShops }

export default reducers
```

I navigate to another route using push:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
  setNearbyShops: nearbyShops => setNearbyShops(nearbyShops),
  goToNearbyShops: (latitude, longitude, radius) => push(`/nearby/@${latitude},${longitude},${radius}`)
}, dispatch)
```

What i want is that userLocation and nearbyShops state gets synced when i navigate back and forth through history so the components gets renderd with the correct state and not with the latest one.

Here is a gif to explain further the issue i'm trying to resolve:

[image: The history location is updated when pressing back but not the data state]

Comment: Hey, I'm having the exact same issue, posted here https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5974 please comment if you solve and its not a package issue

Comment: I'll do for sure!

Comment: Hey so i think i have a final answer for you, that feature is not part of react-router-redux.  You/we are looking for something more like this https://github.com/omnidan/redux-undo, or just write our own middleware to handle sync of browser url with data state via session storage

Comment: or one to do it is to intercept browser back and next buttons and make it work with redux-undo somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to make your UI directly dependent on the history state.
Unfortunately, this is rather fiddly with the existing redux wrappers for react-router.

So when the history changed, your `App` component will receive a prop update.
You'll have to forward these new props in some way to the components that should react to them.
You can e.g. dispatch the new information to the store in the method `componentWillReceiveProps` of you `App` component.

Or you can forward the prop through multiple component layers to where they are needed, but I'd advice against this.

Alternatively, try `https://github.com/mksarge/redux-first-routing` instead, which makes imho much more sense.
It makes routing independent of components.
See also this article:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-introduction-to-the-redux-first-routing-model-98926ebf53cb

One way or the other, `userLocation` and `nearbyShops` should not be reducers, but selectors, as their information can and should be derived from the geo location in your history.

Comment: would you please explain further? I don't see how using selectors will resolve my issue with maintaining a store history across navigation.

Comment: You said your router location state does get updated.
You could derive the geo location and nearby stores in (possibly cached selectors) from this correctly updating state in the the store.

I assume the geo coordinates are in the browser location?

Comment: I've edited the post to display a gif in order to explain the issue better. When i press back the path gets updated to its previous state but the store keeps its last state

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to clarify my answer.